# How to hangout with smoking dudes but not inhaling 2nd hand smoke

Tags: air, smoking

Whenever my dudes go to lunch or coffee breaks, afterwards they smoke while I don't so it is hard for me to breathe. I am not a smoker, but I still want to hang out with my dudes. How can I hang out with them but still keep my lungs good?

Comment: Only two things work, have them stop smoking or not hang out with them. Neither meet your question requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is pretty much nothing you can do about this other than keeping some distance from them or requesting them not to smoke when you are around (you may cook up some health issues like asthma,etc)

You can also consider wearing an anti pollution mask. You can again give reasons like too much pollution/protection from viral diseases etc

Comment: Pretending to have a serious health issue when you don't is a terrible idea, even if the targets aren't people the op is going to interact with on a daily basis..

Answer (score 5):

If it's a breezy day, stand up-wind from them.

Comment: You can even tell your dudes that you're doing that intentionally, so they help keep the smoke off your clothes and out of your lungs. You know, if they're _considerate_ dudes.

Comment: yeah I'd say they are considerate since they move away from us and they blow smoke away from us